CUDAプロジェクト上のCMakeLists.txtでtarget_link_librariesが使えない
JetBrains CLion(ツールチェーンとしてMicrosoft Visual Studio 2022)を用いてC++プロジェクトのサブディレクトリにCUDAコードを置き、それらをライブラリ化してmain.cppにて使用できるようにすることを試みています。
しかし、一方のPCにて問題なくビルドできたプログラムが、別のPCではビルドエラーを起こします。
問題が発生しているサブディレクトリのCMakeLists.txtは以下の内容です。
find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)

set(CUDA_SOURCES source1.cu
                 source2.cu
                 source3.cu
                 source4.cu
                 source5.cu
                 source6.cu)
set(CUDA_HEADERS header1.cuh
                 header2.cuh
                 header3.cuh
                 header4.cuh
                 header5.cuh
                 header6.cuh)

add_library(cuda_project ${CUDA_SOURCES} ${CUDA_HEADERS})
target_compile_features(cuda_project PRIVATE cuda_std_20)

target_link_libraries(cuda_project PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)
target_link_libraries(cuda_project PUBLIC CUDA::curand)

エラー内容は以下の通りです。
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified

実際に必要最小限のコードを記述したtest.cuファイルを作成し、
add_library(cuda_project test.cu)
target_compile_features(cuda_project PRIVATE cuda_std_20)

のみの記述にすると、ビルドは問題なく通りました。
しかし、末尾に以下の1行を戻しただけで再び同じビルドエラーとなりました。
target_link_libraries(cuda_project PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)

また、試しにtarget_compile_optionsを追加した場合にも同じエラーが発生しました。
一体この現象の原因は何なのでしょうか？
参考までに、CMakeのバージョンは3.28、CUDAのバージョンは12.6(ビルドに成功したPCとエラーが発生しているPCともにバージョンは同じ)です。
